# Google calendar like view in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, google-calendar-api

I am building a share point site wherein I am trying to get multiple calenders in a single view. I have been able to overlay/merge calenders but I am unable to make the select/unselect of a calender from a set of merged calenders seamless.

Explaining using the feature from google calender - basically, when using multiple calendars in google calender, the calendars menu is on the left. clicking on each individual calendar will hide the calendar if it is already displayed or show it if it is hidden.

In sharepoint clicking the calendar in overlay view opens that particular calendar. what I want to achieve is a view where all calendars are overlayed and can be shown or hidden by a simple mouse input.

Has anyone done this before? Any pointers? Thanks